# MongoDB conditional data update shows error

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB with NodeJS. I have user database like below:

```
db.user.insertOne({
  email: "user2@email.com",
  name: "First Last",
  age: 55,
analytics: [   { date: "2023-03-25", country: { UK: 1 }, browser: {}, os: {} },
  { date: "2023-03-26", country: {}, browser: {}, os: {} },
  { date: "2023-03-27", country: {}, browser: {}, os: {} },
  { date: "2023-03-28", country: {}, browser: {}, os: {} },
  { date: "2023-03-29", country: { UK: 1, AU: 5 }, browser: {}, os: {} },]}
);
```

Here is what I want to do:
I want to do a `findOneAndUpdate` query. If today's date exists in the analytics array then it will update the country browser and os fields data. If the date does not exist inside the analytics array then it will create a new object like `{ date: "2023-03-25", country: { UK: 1 }, browser: { Opera: 1 }, os: { Windows: 1 } }`

I tried doing query like these, but it shows `Updating the path 'analytics.$[element].country.UK' would create a conflict at 'analytics'`

```
db.user.findOneAndUpdate(
   { email: "user2@email.com" },
   {
      $set: { "analytics.$[element].date": "2023-03-31", "analytics.$[element].country": {"UK": 1}, "analytics.$[element].browser": {"Opera": 1}, "analytics.$[element].os" : {"Windows": 1} },
      $inc: { "analytics.$[element].country.UK": 1, "analytics.$[element].browser.Opera" : 1, "analytics.$[element].os.Windows" : 1 }
   },
   {
      arrayFilters: [{ "element.date": "2023-03-30" }],
      upsert: true,
      returnOriginal: false
   }
)
```

Is there any way to conditionally update this in a single `findOneAndUpdate` query or using other method?
Code examples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It can be done with an aggregation query. Why do you limit your solution to `findOneAndUpdate`?

Comment: Can you please write an example? `upsert` is supported on `findOneAndUpdate` method, that's why I thought that way.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use update with pipeline:

1. Separate the `analytics` array into two parts: `analytics` until today and `today`.
2. Increase today's relevant counters or create them if needed
3. Concatenate `analytics` with today.

```
db.user.findOneAndUpdate (
  {email: "user2@email.com"},
  [{$set: {
      today: {$cond: [
          {$eq: [{$last: "$analytics.date"}, "2023-03-31"]},
          {$last: "$analytics"},
          {date: "2023-03-31", country: {}, browser: {}, os: {}}
      ]},
      analytics: {$ifNull: [
          {$filter: {
          input: "$analytics",
          cond: {$ne: ["$$this.date", "2023-03-31"]}}}, []
      ]}
  }},
  {$set: {
      "today.country": {$cond: [
          {$eq: [
              {$size: {$filter: {
                    input: {$objectToArray: "$todayt.country"},
                    cond: {$eq: ["$$this.k", "UK"]}
              }}}, 0
          ]},
          {$mergeObjects: ["$today.country", {UK: 1}]},
          {$mergeObjects: ["$today.country", {UK: {$add: ["$today.country.UK", 1]}}]}
      ]},
      "today.browser": {$cond: [
          {$eq: [
              {$size: {$filter: {
                    input: {$objectToArray: "$today.browser"},
                    cond: {$eq: ["$$this.k", "Opera"]}
              }}}, 0
          ]},
          {$mergeObjects: ["$today.browser", {Opera: 1}]},
          {$mergeObjects: ["$today.browser", {Opera: {$add: ["$today.browser.Opera", 1]}}]}
      ]},
      "today.os": {$cond: [
          {$eq: [
              {$size: {$filter: {
                    input: {$objectToArray: "$today.os"},
                    cond: {$eq: ["$$this.k", "Windows"]}
              }}}, 0
          ]},
          {$mergeObjects: ["$today.os", {Windows: 1}]},
          {$mergeObjects: ["$today.os", {Windows: {$add: ["$today.os.Windows", 1]}}]}
      ]}
  }},
  {$set: {
      analytics: {$concatArrays: ["$analytics", ["$today"]]},
      today: "$$REMOVE"
  }}],
  {upsert: true}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B7JMYVJDcTy)